# How to specify output_shape parameter in Lambda layer in Keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

I don't understand how to specify the `output_shape` parameter in the `Lambda` layer in Keras/Tensorflow. The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda) says:

> output_shape: Expected output shape from function. This argument can
> be
> inferred if not explicitly provided. Can be a tuple or function. If a
> tuple, it only specifies the first dimension onward;
> sample dimension is assumed either the same as the input: `output_shape = (input_shape[0], ) + output_shape` or, the input is `None` and
> the sample dimension is also `None`: `output_shape = (None, ) + output_shape`

If we use a tuple how should I interpret these two expressions?

`output_shape = (input_shape[0], ) + output_shape`

and

`output_shape = (None, ) + output_shape`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you pass in output_shape as a tuple `(50, 50, 10)` where we can call the values (height, width, channels)` to the lambda layer:

```
your_layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x, output_shape=(50, 50, 3))
```

The part of the documentation:

> If a tuple, it only specifies the first dimension onward;

means that the `batch` dimensions itself is simple carried forward, unchanged.

If you have e.g. `batch_size=3` during training, the incoming tensor to `your_layer` might be `(3, n, p, q)`, where `n` `p` and `q` could be anything, but the layer is expected to produce a shape `(3, 50, 50, 10)`. So the `0` dimension remains unchanged, and we have concatenated it with your `output_shape`:

```
(3,) + (50, 50, 10) -> (3, 50, 50, 10)
```

This corresponds to the expression: `output_shape = (input_shape[0], ) + output_shape`, so we see that `input_shape` is the true shape of the ***incoming batch tensor*** during training, as we only took the batch dimension to produce the layer's ***outgoing batch tensor***.

For the second expression it is really just the same thing, but if you haven't provided a batch shape, Tensorflow & Keras represent that as something that could be anything, and store it as `None`. So in that case you get:

```
(None,) + (50, 50, 10) -> (None, 50, 50, 10)
```